# Understanding ng-if and DOM compilation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have two `ng-if`s defined in the same template that call functions of the same controller:

```
<div ng-controller="UserController">
    <!-- WORKS :) -->
    <p>{{ user.name }}</p>

    <!--WORKS :)-->
    <div ng-if="showThingOne()">
        <h2>Thing One</h2>
    </div>

    <!--DOESN'T WORK :( ; TypeError: Cannot read property 'role' of undefined -->
    <div ng-if="showThingTwo(user)">
        <h2>Thing Two</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('UserController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'User', function ($rootScope, $scope, User) {
        var getCurrentUser = function () {
            User.current(function (user) {
               $scope.user = user;
               $rootScope.currentUser = user;
            });
        };
        getCurrentUser();

        $scope.showThingOne = function () {
            return $scope.user.role === 'Thing One Seer';  
        };

        $scope.showThingTwo = function (user) {
            return user.role === 'Thing Two Seer';  
        };
    }]);
```

The second conforms with a bunch of things I've read about unit testing, while the first is always marked "Don't do it this way", so I'd like to write my functions the second way. Also, I'd like to understand *why* the first works and the second doesn't; I'm guessing it has something to do with how the DOM is compiled during $digest, but that's just a random guess with no real support in the Angular source or docs.

Comment: Define "Doesn't Work"? Your first ng-if has an HTML fragment to render, the second does the same as the first except it takes an  input parameter it doesn't use and has no HTML fragment to render.

Comment: Fixed the HTML and added the error message for "doesn't work."

Comment: you are passing `user` as a parameter to the second example, but not using it, still checking against `$scope`.  Try just `user.role` instead of `$scope.user.role`

Comment: Whoops, yeah, actually that was the whole point of my question. I've fixed it to what I actually have in my project that is causing the `TypeError`. If I use the `$scope` then it works fine, regardless of what arguments are or are not passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The User.current is an async function so the result get ready after the dom compiled.

showThingOne has no argument to be evaluated at compile time.

**Solution**

Add

```
 $scope.user = {};
```

as the first line of user controller.

```
   angular.module('MyApp')
        .controller('UserController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'User', function ($rootScope, $scope, User) {
$scope.user = {};
            var getCurrentUser = function () {
                User.current(function (user) {
                   $scope.user = user;
                   $rootScope.currentUser = user;
                });
            };
            getCurrentUser();

            $scope.showThingOne = function () {
                return $scope.user.role === 'Thing One Seer';  
            };

            $scope.showThingTwo = function (user) {
                return user.role === 'Thing Two Seer';  
            };
        }]);
```

Comment: That did it; it's a simple thing that is included in most beginner articles without really explaining why it's necessary. Now I know :)

Comment: @dyelawn This doesn't explain why `showThingOne` works. It shouldn't in my opinion for the same reason. `$scope.user` is not defined when the expression is first evaluated. I created a [**plunk**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SOrnGzPZcptwV5ewRgUG?p=preview) and both are failing like expected (check the console). Are you sure that the function without arguments was working?

Comment: @plalx yeah, I'm successfully running functions with both styles right now.

Comment: @plalx your controller in your sample does not execute. Just add an alert in the first line of your controller.

Comment: @dyelawn Yeah, I understand why it works **now**, but `showThingOne` should not have been working without `$scope.user = {};` for the very same reason that `$scope.user` was undefined. @Alborz It works fine in Chrome and the `alert` does show up if I put one inside the function that defines `TestCtrl`. http://plnkr.co/edit/SOrnGzPZcptwV5ewRgUG?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because `user` is never being used:

```
$scope.showThingTwo = function (user) {
    return $scope.user.role === 'Thing Two Seer';  
};
```

Only `$scope.user.role` is being used (but not the `user` parameter) and it is still set to the `'Thing One Seer'` value.

If you use it like this it might work this way you are intenting:

```
$scope.showThingTwo = function (user) {
    if (user) {
        return user.role === 'Thing Two Seer';  
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake on my part while typing up the question. In my actual project, I do use `user.role` instead of `$scope.user.role`, and that's what's causing the confusion.

Comment: OK, In that case, user is probably null before `$scope.user` is resolved to a value.  Can you add a null check?

Comment: Yeah, it is undefined, that's what I understood from the type error. What I don't understand is *why* it is undefined, especially since the bound value `{{ user.name }}` in the `<p>` works fine.